# Iterate PictureBoxes

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

How can I iterate through PictureBoxes named PictureBox1, PictureBox2 ... PictureBox24 in Visual Basic 10

Answer (score 2):

You should give your `PictureBox`es meaningful names and if you have that many picture boxes you should put them into an array.

Apart from that, having that many picture boxes hurts performance. You are probably using them to draw individual objects – *don’t do that*! Use *one* picture box and draw everything on it.

But if you really want to, you can iterate the parent control’s `Controls` collection.

```
For Each control As Control In parent.Controls
    Dim pictureBox As PictureBox = TryCast(control, PictureBox)
    If pictureBox IsNot Nothing Then … ' Do something.
End For
```

Where `parent` is the parent control (e.g. the form) that contains the picture boxes.